# Quad graphs in Java

Tags: java, graph

I'm trying to make a quad graph, but it's coming out as solid black instead of lines. Can anyone help?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Hawks extends Panel
{

// paint gets called whenever window is changed
// This paint draws a red filled circle at coordinates
// x=100 y=200, with diameter = 20.
public void paint(Graphics baby)
{
    int xloc,yloc;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    while (x<1000)
    {
        xloc=x+5;
        yloc=y+2;
    baby.setColor(new Color(16,15,15));
    baby.drawLine(xloc,0,xloc,1000);
    x++;
    y++;
    xloc++;
    }


    }

}
```

Comment: It's generally discouraged to override paint, but instead it's generally recommended that you call paintComponent. You should also be calling super.paintXxx (spending on which paint method you've overridden) as the paint methods chain together to generate the desire results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code draws a vertical line for every pixel between 5 and 1005. If you wish to space out these lines, then increment the x value the appropriate number of pixels. For instance, to draw a vertical line every 10 pixels along the x-axis (using your names and syntax):

```
int x = 0;
int increment = 10;
baby.setColor(new Color(16,15,15));
while ( x < 1000 ){
    x += increment;
    baby.drawLine(x, 0, x, 1000);
}
```